# Real example code for software pipelining

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, llvm, pipelining

I'm currently finding a way that can show how software pipelining is applied to the code.

```
for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
    D[i] = A[i] * B[i] + 1;
}
```

I found the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479059/software-pipelining-example-with-gcc) with the answer using gcc option <-fsel-sched-pipelining>, however, it didn't show any difference after applying the option.

Is there any compiler option that shows software pipelining?

Comment: Alternatively you could use https://godbolt.org/ and work backwards from the assembler generated.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can you be more specific with working backwards?

Comment: I just mean read the assembly code and see what optimisation tricks it has used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **llvm**-based compiler, **machinepipeliner** is the pass doing the magic, which it's a back-end pass and may not be enabled on your compiler/ under the optimisation level you used or somehow the compiler deemed that the code fed was not eligible for this particular optimisation.

If you have a **debug version** of the compiler you are using, you could simply use the `--debug-pass=Structure` flag to verify if there was a "machine pipeliner" pass run at all, and if it was, using the `-mllvm -debug-only=pipeliner` flag, you would be able to see the detailed steps of the algorithm, whether it succeeded or failed to produce a schedule and the resulted code.

With a **release version**, your options are limited though, one thing you could do is to use the `-mllvm -print-after-all` flag and search for "Modulo Software Pipelining" to verify if the pass was run and the effect of the pass on the IR.